# Программист 3d игр с точки зрения работодателя

Tags: работа

Вымышленный работодатель хочет выпускать компьютерные 3д игры

Он хочет нанять первую партию программистов которые бы начали процесс создания игры в стиле контр-страйка либо портала.

Что должны знать эти программисты?

Как работодателю ничего не смыслевшему в 3д играх найти действительно грамотных людей?

Что он должен указать в вакансии и на что опираться?

Comment: Правильный ответ - никак или нанять себе менеджера, который разрулит эти вопросы.

Comment: ну менеджеры грамотные тоже не валяются на дороге. Можно купить контору например геймдевовскую если денег много.

Comment: выучить русский язык как вариант еще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I) Если бюджет маленький:

Создать вымышленный аккаунт на фриланс сайтах. 
Обозначить бюджет например 500$.

Задача:
Полное консультирование по всем вопросам разработки игр 3D.
В дальнейшем возможно составление ТЗ и плана работ, для создания 3D игры в жанре N.

Среди ответивших, ищем тех, у кого в примерах работ есть игры. Спрашиваем у них как они создавали это, какие есть сложности. Какие были сроки, затраты , какой нужен персонал и еще 100 вопросов которые нужно аккуратно записать в тетрадь перед началом деятельности.

А еще можно самому скачать готовые движки(довольно простой irrlicht.ru) и месяц в них покрутится, посмотреть как примерно может выглядеть разработка. Многие простые вопросы отпадут сами собой. Углубляться дальше в 3D математику, дизайн нет смысла, так как это займет долгие годы, а хороший управляющий тоже нужен.

II) Если бюджет средний.
Найм опытного сотрудника. Не того у кого много знаний или дипломов, а именно опытного, который участвовал в разработке игры вашей направленности. Это необходимо перепроверить несколько раз. То есть в вакансии следует написать, чтобы предоставили примеры работ и по возможности будете звонить предыдущему работодателю. 
Никаких инноваций, 21 века, только опыт опыт опыт, кто прошел разработку от А до Я.
На зарплате жалеть не стоит.

III) Если бюджет большой. 
Здесь вопросов быть не должно. Идите к 1С.